# What is the effect of case sensitive boolean operator in solr query

Tags: time, solr

In Solr query , when I used ***OR***(Caps letter) , the query processing time is ***172*** ***ms***.But when I used ***or*** (small letter),the query processing time is ***109 ms***.What is the effect of using case sensitive Boolean operator in solr search query...?

following is my query

//mydoamin:8983/solr/C62/select?q=content(every) or contentstem(every)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boolean Operators according to [Query Parser Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Boolean%20operators) are Case Sensitive.

```
Boolean operators must be ALL CAPS
```

So when you use OR it is actually and OR query.
However, lower case or would be a normal text search which will be faster then boolean.

Please check the Query that is formed using the Debug option.